# Hunter ceiling fan stopped working but is working again

Tags: ceiling-fan

We have had our Hunter ceiling fan four about 2 years, no issues. As of yesterday we went to turn on the fan and it would not move, just a faint humming noise like it was trying to work. The lights would still work. From time to time there was a very short click/catching noise coming from within the motor of the fan. I tried to spin the fan manually to get it started with no luck. We left it off over night and all of the sudden this afternoon it is working again, however it is still making the short click/catching noise. I've turned it off and back on today and it works. Any ideas of what could be causing this? I'm afraid it will stop working again.

Thanks

****EDIT****

As of 20 minutes ago we noticed a burning smell coming from the fan. I have since flipped the breaker and uninstalled the fan. There is a very strong burning odor coming from the motor. Contacting Hunter, hopefully they will help...

Comment: what does this mean? ... `I tried to spin the fan manually` ... it would not spin at all or it did spin but would not run

Answer (score 1):

Contacting the manufacturer is a good call and probably your best solution at this point. Unfortunately after 2 years, any sort of warranty will have expired. Still they may want to know the details of your incident for R&D purposes.

If you smell burning electronics, it is always wise to get them inspected and replaced. That smell means there was heat in the electronics. Heat means damage. Damage means failure. Failure at your household voltages could mean fire or electrocution.

I'm not sure if the click/catching sound was the fault of the fan or not. Something I noticed with one of the fans in my house was that the clicking/catching noise came from the wires from the ceiling rubbing on the fan motor housing and catching on the screws that held the device together. If you hear this kind of sound from a different fan, check the wiring to make sure it's not rubbing the insulation off!

Also inspect the wiring now to make sure the burning smell didn't come from the insulation. If any of the insulation is damaged, you will need to replace the wiring to that fan.